# I think my computer has two desktops and I don't know how to remove the extra one

Tags: windows-xp, multiple-monitors, desktop, display-settings

I think my computer has two desktops - I have no idea how to remove the second one which I never use, not that I know how to use it anyway. If I take my mouse pointer out of the upper bounds of my visible desktop and slide it up high and then bring it back down, it takes a lot of sliding before I can see it back on my visible desktop. More importantly when I take a screen capture, it shows a blank desktop above whatever is visible to me.

I have no idea what to do. How can I resolve this?

[image: My Desktop]

Comment: The image link for my desktop http://i.imgur.com/n2AGP.jpg

Comment: I added the image to your question for you! ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click on the desktop and select Properties. Go to the Settings tab and see how many monitors are enabled.  I'm willing to bet that you will have two stacked on top of each other.  To disable the top monitor, select it in the window and uncheck the box "Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor".

Comment: You sir, are a great man. That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.