# 2nd Monitor Removed but Desktop Remains

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, extended-desktop

I have the same problem as this question:

[I think my computer has two desktops and I don't know how to remove the extra one](https://superuser.com/questions/195183/i-think-my-computer-has-two-desktops-and-i-dont-know-how-to-remove-the-extra-on/195187#195187)

However when I try the solution proposed I don't seem to have 2 monitors

I can use my 'hand' to try and drag the screen marked 1 as much as possible but there doesn't seem to be anything underneath.

Using Windows 7 Home Premium

Any advice would be useful. Thanks

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hn8gygf9kckrml4/Clipboard01.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [I think my computer has two desktops and I don't know how to remove the extra one](http://superuser.com/questions/195183/i-think-my-computer-has-two-desktops-and-i-dont-know-how-to-remove-the-extra-on)

Comment: Why do you think you have two desktops? Is this a new problem?

Comment: @jawa It is a duplicate but I didn't have enough reputation to comment - and thus say that the solution provided wasn't suitable.

Comment: @CharlieRB It's an old problem that I sporadically try and fix - mainly because some software always appears on the second desktop which is irritating - but have yet to solve.

Comment: @CharlieRB edited to add link to image. Can't post image direcdtly

Comment: Is the area with the water fall usable at all? Do you have the proper drivers installed for the monitor you're using?

Comment: @CharlieRB I can't see of access the are with the waterfall. I can move my mouse there and have dragged windows back from it by estimating where the window bar is an then click and dragging. I've also updated the drivers and been told I have the latest drivers. I assume that there is something in the registry that would turn this off/on but....